# Equivalent properties of affine subsets

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm sure I'm making a simple error somewhere, but I haven't been able to pinpoint it.

Linear Algebra Done Right 3.85 states that:

Suppose $U$ is a subspace of $V$ and $v,w\in V$. Then the following are equivalent:

- $v-w\in U$;
- $v+U=w+U$;
- $(v+U) \cap(w+U)\neq \varnothing $

Here's my counterexample:

$V = R^2$

$v=(10,0)$

$w=(7,0)$

$U=\{(x+3,2x) \in R^2: x \in R\}$

Here, $v-w=(3,0)$, which is clearly in $U$. However, $v+U=\{(x+13,2x) \in R^2: x \in R\}$, whereas $w+U=\{(x+10,2x) \in R^2: x \in R\}$. These are clearly different, parallel lines, so how can $v+U=w+U$?

Comment: U is not a subspace. For that matter, $U$ does not contain the additive identity!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $U$ is not a subspace. That's the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Since I have already pinpointed the mistake, I'll give a proof.

We go $i) \implies ii) \implies iii) \implies i)$

$i) \implies ii)$ : Suppose $v-w \in U$. We have to show that $v+U=w+U$. We do this by the following chain:

$x \in v + U \iff x = v+u, u \in U  \iff x = w + ((v-w) + u), u \in U \iff x \in w + U$, as $(v-w) + u \in U$.

$ii) \implies iii)$: Suppose that $v+U=w+U$. Obivously if they are equal then their intersection is not empty, unless both are empty, which is not possible as one contains $v$ and the other $w$.

$iii) \implies i)$: Suppose that $x \in (v+U) \cap (w+U)$. Then there exist $u_1$ and $u_2$ such that $x = v+u_1=w+u_2$. Therefore, $v-w=u_2-u_1$, therefore $v-w \in U$ as $u_2-u_1 \in U$ because $U$ is a subspace.

Hence the proof.